# Relevant Prior Art for "Time domain reflectometer touch screen sensor"?

Tags: prior-art-request

**Resolved** - patent examiner independently struck down claims - see comment below.

Does anybody know of any prior art related to [US20110128257](http://www.google.com/patents/US20110128257) ?

The patent [US20110128257](http://www.google.com/patents/US20110128257) claims a provisional application date of Nov 29 2009.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking -- please see the help pages for how to format different types of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is prior art at least for claims 1 and 2:

[Huang, C.F. Precise Location of Touch Panel by Employing the Time-Domain Reflectometry. SID Symposium Digest of Technical Papers, 40(1), June 2009, pp. 1291-1293.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1889/1.3256532/abstract)

and possibly

Collins, Ryan V. Methods and apparatus for receiving user
input via time domain reflectometry. US-Patent 2004/0239616 A1

Furthermore, the general principle of touch sensing using TDR has already been described in 1964:

> "In exposed circuits one can touch the line to produce an added echo.
>   Then, by running the point of contact along the line till this added
>   echo coincides with the system echoes, one can literally put his
>   fingers on the troubles. In a coaxial cable, one can produce a
>   reflection by squeezing the cable."

[Oliver, B. M. Time Domain Reflectometry, HP Journal 15(6), 1964.](http://www.hpl.hp.com/hpjournal/pdfs/IssuePDFs/1964-02.pdf)

---

**Edit:** According to the Public PAIR, the patent examiner struck down claims 1-5 as being already described by [Kozik et al. (US 5149918)](http://www.google.com/patents/US5149918). The patent only refers to optical TDR now.